# DataGrip - [08004] The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided by plugin null

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I am trying to start coding postgresql in Jetbrains Datagrip on my ubuntu. in the console I tried to create a database first using the following command `create database test;`. but I got this error:

```
Connecting to posgres@localhost
[08004] The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided by plugin null
```

I tried to change the credentials to `No auth` or change the user to root user and password or my user and password. but it did not help.

Comment: It looks like IDE can't establish connection to db and db asks to provide credentials. Do you run a local PostgreSQL instance?